# WordPress Page and Blog Integration

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I currently run a self hosted WordPress website; on a VPS Server.

I am currently building my content and trying to configure my website structure and layout.  It is within this area where I have an issue that I hope can be resolved.

At present, my website will be providing 3 services.  Each service will have its own Page.  In the interest of building my SEO strategy, I would like to create a series of Blogs that are specific to each service and thus Page.  I would like the layout for each service to appear as follows:

*Home > Service Page > Service Blog Post*

I would like the 'Home' and 'Service Page' to be in a page format with the 'Service Blog Post' to be in a Blog post format.  Whilst I know how to create a page and a blog page, I am uncertain of how to create these both whilst maintaining the above breadcrumb/URL structure.  I have tried experimenting with the Categories function but as you are probably aware, I can get to the 'Service Page' but as soon as I click through to the 'Service Blog Post', I get redirected to the URL of: categories/blog-post.

I am unsure if it is possible to achieve the above but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Craig

Comment: You can use custom post types along with page templates displaying the posts from each custom post type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom post types are the way to go.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

This will allow you to define the slug(url) directory for the given service to be something like /service-type/service-blog-post and /service-type/ should display the archive of service-type blogs.

When you run the register post type hook you will define that slug here:

```
register_post_type( 'service-type', $args );
```

If custom post types are new to you then I'd recommend checking out https://generatewp.com/ as it gives you a simple interface to build out a custom post type as well as other wordpress functions.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  Custom post types are new to me, so will have to do some background reading first but will give this a go.  Before I go ahead, can I create custom post types for different services/categories or can I only create one custom post type?

Comment: You can create as many different custom post types as you want.  There are plugins out there that will handle this for you but I'd recommend using the code in your functions.php file of your theme.

Comment: I am having a little difficulty in trying to achieve my result. To ensure that I am not spending time on custom post types in vain, let me double check that this is the right area I should be in as to achieve my desired goal. At present, I have a website URL as follows:  http://www.example.com/page1/page2. The pages have been created through the page option on the WordPress Dashboard. My next step is to be able to then post blog entries as to appear at the end of the URL as follows:  http://www.example.com/page1/page2/blog-post-title. Is the custom post type the right function to achieve this?